# Selecting an appended element in table through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to select a div element that has 2 child elements. They are appended as you can see in the code below. I've tried for hours now without any success. How would I go about to select the div with ".input-form" and it's children??

```
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md">
            <h1 class="m-5">Our Shoes</h1>
            <table class="shoe-table">
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
```

and my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  let $table = $(".shoe-table");
  let $inputForm = $(".input-form"); //This is not working....

  fetch("shoes.json")
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(data => {
      let shoes = data.shoes;
      console.log(shoes)
      let rows = [1, 2, 3];
      let shoeCard = "";
      let counter = 0;
      rows.forEach(row => {
        shoeCard += "<tr>";
        for (let index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
          console.log(shoes[counter].image);

          shoeCard += "<td class='card text-center'>" + "<img class='card-img-top' src=" + shoes[counter].image + " alt='Card image cap'>" +
            "<h5 class='card-title'>" + shoes[counter].name + "</h5>" +
            "<p class='card-text'>kr " + shoes[counter].price + "</p>" +
            "<button id='orderNow' class='btn btn-outline-dark'>ORDER NOW</button>" +
            "<div class='input-form'><input type='number' placeholder='Choose quantity' min=0 max=10><br>" +
            "<button class='btn-add-to-cart' disabled='disabled'>ADD TO CART</button>"
          "</div>"
          "</td>";
          counter++;
        }
        shoeCard += "</tr>";
      });
      $table.append(shoeCard);
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));

  $("body").delegate("#orderNow", "click", function() {
    console.log("FUNKAR");
    $inputForm.toggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: The line you have flagged as `not working` tries to select an element with ID `input-form` (`#` means ID). It fails bcs you have no elements with that ID, only elements with that *class*.  You would select them with `$('.input-form')`.  However you will then run into another very common problem - selectors and event handlers only match elements which exist at the time the DOM is loaded. You are adding new elements after page load, and your selectors won't match them. Move the declaration of that selector inside your event handler so it is evaluated once the element exists.

Comment: `.delegate` is deprecated, you should use `.on`

Comment: Thank you, you were right about moving it in to the event handler!